# Django Mptt: filtering based on child category

Tags: django, django-views, django-mptt

I use django-mptt for Category model and I have Service model as well.

The problem:

- I got all services associated to node category by clicking on a child category.

What I want:

- I want to get all services associated to child category that I click. I believe I have to check it in an additional step in views (ServiceByCategoryListView). But I have no idea how to do that. Google doesn’t help me.

```
models.py

class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    preparation = models.TextField()
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    available = models.BooleanField(default='True')
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='services')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', 
                            on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
                            null=True, 
                            blank=True, 
                            related_name='children',
                            db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['parent', 'slug']]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('services-by-category', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category-list'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', ServiceByCategoryListView.as_view(), name='services-by-category'),
]
```

```
views.py

class CategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'main/category_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['services'] = Service.objects.all()
        return context


class ServiceByCategoryListView(ListView):
    model = Service
    context_object_name = 'services'
    template_name = 'main/service_list.html'
    

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.category = Category.objects.filter(parent=None).get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        branch_categories = self.category.get_descendants(include_self=True)
        queryset = Service.objects.filter(category__in=branch_categories)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['name'] = self.category
        return context
```

I tried to find a solution in django-mptt documentation but have no result. Also I tried to use Q objects but I was not able to find a correct solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood the problem correctly, but if you want to have all the services associated with the child category you're clicking on, without the services of the category you're clicking on, you need to set include_self=False in the get_queryset of your ServiceByCategoryListView class.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try to explain this way. 

Now everything works like this: I click on a node category(Category) and print child categories(for example: Category_Child1, Category _Child2 and etc.).  And when I click on any child category, I get all services associated with node category (Category). But I have to get only services which associated to the child category that I click.

Comment: If you only need to retrieve the services associated with the category you click on, why retrieve the parent category (`Category.objects.filter(parent=None).get(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])`) and then retrieve the children rather than directly retrieving the child category and retrieving the services associated with that category?

Comment: How do you think this can be implemented? Btw, slug for main parent category is needed for urls. Now urls looks like this: /parent_category_slug/. but ideally it should look like this: /parent_category_slug/child_category_slug

Comment: Why not remove the parent category slug and insert the child category slug directly?

otherwise, if you want to have this url: "/parent_category_slug/child_category_slug"
You need to modify the url like this: 
path('<slug:parent_slug>/<slug:child_slug>/', ServiceByCategoryListView.as_view(), name='services-by-category')

And then to retrieve the child in the view: 
self.child_category = Category.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['slug:child_slug'])
queryset = Service.objects.filter(category=self.child_category)

Comment: I edited my code like you advised but now I got an error: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'services-by-category' with keyword arguments '{'child_slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<parent_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P<child_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z'] I think it happens because of this function:def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('services-by-category', kwargs={'slug': self.slug}). What I have to write here?

Comment: I am trying this : return reverse('services-by-category', kwargs={'parent_slug': self.parent.slug, 'child_slug': self.child.slug})but AttributeError at /
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'slug'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).